# Check that regex subpattern does not contain a previous subpattern?

Tags: regex, recursion

I am wondering if there is a way to check a subpattern match for a given sequence so I can block it.

For example, lets say that I wanted to capture everything except a repeat of an earlier capture. So if I had the sentence `[word plus word]` the following should capture everything (`word plus`) up to the second occurrence of `word`.

```
(\w+)[^\1]+
```

The first `(\w+)` captures `word`. The second `[^...]` capture group tries to exclude it (it being the `\1` captured earlier), but it only works on characters - not subpattern captures.

So is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use patterns like this:

```
(\w+)(?:(?!\1).)*
```

Which uses a negative lookahead to assert (at every character) that the previously matched word is not contained in the subexpression.

Comment: That's it, you need more points for this. I've used this answer a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could use lazy quantifiers and lookaround, like this:

```
(\w+).*?(?=\1)
```

you may also want to surround w+ with word boundaries like this:

```
\b(\w+)\b.*?(?=\1)
```

so that you don't match things like this: hello where you would match the "ll"

Comment: `(\w+).*?(?!\1)` won't work properly, in `foo barfoo` it would match `foo`, when `foo bar` is desired. Maybe you meant `(\w+).*?(?=\1|$)`.